# What am I doing wrong in my JavaScript switch statement?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Below I have various input fields to which I calculate in the end result for month gain and year gain based on the initial income value.

What I am trying to do is add radio buttons to select weather the values they are inserting are for weekly, monthly etc...

I posted as an example the first value of income where i need the user to decide with a checkbox...

```
function computeBudget() {        
        var income = document.getElementById('income').value;
        switch(rate) {
            case weekly:
                this.add((.value * 52) / 12);
                break;
            case biWeekly:
                this.add((.value * 26) / 12);
                break;
        }

        var grocery_expenses = document.getElementById('grocery_expenses').value;
        var car_insurance = document.getElementById('car_insurance').value;
        var home_mortgage = document.getElementById('home_mortgage').value;
        var home_utilities = document.getElementById('home_utilities').value;
        var life_insurance = document.getElementById('life_insurance').value;


        var monthgain = (income - grocery_expenses - car_insurance - home_mortgage - home_utilities -life_insurance).toFixed(2);
        monthgain = monthgain.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        document.getElementById('monthgain').innerHTML = "Monthly Net Gain = $"+monthgain ;

        var yeargain = ((income - grocery_expenses - car_insurance - home_mortgage - home_utilities -life_insurance) * 12).toFixed(2);
        yeargain = yeargain.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        document.getElementById('yeargain').innerHTML = "Yearly Net Gain = $"+ yeargain;
    }
```

Comment: does the income value also changes according to the radio button? (can it be in weekly/monthly terms?)

Comment: Should that be `switch(income)`?

Comment: no the income value should be calculated based on the radio button, and then when i see how much he is saving in total every month it will correspond as well as when i use the year calculation

Comment: So what is the `rate` variable? What do you think `(.value * 52)` does? Looks like a syntax error.

Comment: sorry, the input they put should be attached to the radio button so if i get a check every 2 months i would put 4,000 in the input field and then check 2 months radio button which will calculate in the tend result to show how much i have extra in savings every month and year

Comment: i just put rate there but i figure i should do this switch case for every variable like grocery expenses and car insurance, or maybe i just ned to make the switch statement once.. i really dont know

Comment: ok so switch(income) and change (.value * 52) = (income *52) ? and then do it for all the variable values. And how do i give each a "id" to call for the radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

Try adding quotes to case values like:

```
switch(rate) {
        case "weekly": // added quotes
            this.add((.value * 52) / 12);
            break;
        case "biWeekly": // added quotes
            this.add((.value * 26) / 12);
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a weekly multiplier variable that will hold the conversion value to weeks.

then, you need to switch on the value of the radio button and create a case for each situation you want to handle.

example:

```
var weekMultiplier = 0;
switch(rate) // a string value representing the type
{
    case "weekly":
        weekMultiplier = 1;
        break;
    case "biWeekly":
        weekMultiplier = 0.5;
        break;
    case "monthly":
        weekMultiplier = 0.25;
        break;
}
```

then you multiply your inputs by this multiplier. you do that for every value you want to include in your calculation, if they are not already converted to their weekly value.

example:

```
var weeklyIncome = income * weekMultiplier;
var weeklyCarInsurance = document.getElementById('car_insurance').value * weekMultiplier;
```

now you can subtract them

```
var weeklyGain = weeklyIncome - weeklyCarInsurance;
```

and multiply the gain for your desired format:

```
var monthlyGain = weeklyGain * 4;
var yearlyGain = weeklyGain * 52;
```

Comment: is there a way to use grouped inputs using name="income" because i was suggested this on another site but it does not seem to change the result.. If it fails i will definatly rewrite the code in the way you described so thanks a grip boss!

Comment: You can place the weekMultiplier values inside each radio button's value. Then you can omit the switch statement and get the multiplier from there